# Basic EM: Infinite energy of magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I thought I was done with EM, but then I encountered a strange question:

> A ring of test mass (m) and test charge (q) with radius R is sitting still in space filled with a uniform B-field in the direction of the axis of the ring: $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B_z}$

What is the work done on the ring when the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ suddenly shuts off.

**I'd like to stress that my issue with this question is not how to do it correctly, but rather why my method for solving it is incorrect.**

I tried solving this via the [magnetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_energy):

$E=\int u dV=\int \frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2 dV$

and saying energy is conserved: $E_{initial}=E_{final}$

But then I realized that if the $\mathbf{B}$ field is uniform in all of space, we get $E=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B_0^2 V_{total}\rightarrow \infty$; but obviously the ring of test mass is not going to have kinetic energy going to infinity.

Comment: While this has nothing to do with your problem, whenever somebody talks about an infinite field volume of this kind, they are just lazy. What they really mean is that there is a finite field region that is sufficiently homogeneous and that it doesn't matter for the problem what happens outside of that region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy of the entire magnetic field in space is infinite, so the change of energy when it shuts off is infinite too. But that's not what the question is asking. It's asking about the work done *on the ring*.

The work will be done through induction. Change of magnetic flux through the ring induces voltage in the ring:

$$U_i=-S\frac{d B}{dt}$$
In a conductive loop, this voltage would send a current through the loop. You'd get the result by $U=RI$ and then whatever you wanted to calculate from the current. In our case, the current will be macroscopic rotation of the ring, so we can get by with more hands-on mechanical calculation.

Induced voltage $U_i$ in a circumference $2\pi R$ means the local electric field tangential to the ring is $E=U_i/(2\pi R)$. This electric field acts on the charge with a force $F=Ee$. This tangential force applies torque on the ring: $M=FR$. And this torque causes angular acceleration $\alpha=M/J$. Angular velocity after the entire thing is over is of course an integral over time of the angular acceleration:

$$\omega=\int_0^\infty \alpha\,dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{S e}{2\pi J}\frac{dB}{dt}\,dt=\frac{Se}{2\pi J}\Delta B$$
yo see that how the field is turned off doesn't matter, only how much it changed.

The kinetic energy of the ring after all is over, is of course
$$\frac12 J\omega^2 = \frac{(Se)^2}{8\pi^2 J}$$
which very obviously isn't infinite.

Comment: Hi @orion , thanks for your effort and for pointing out the way to do the calculation another way. I was wondering why my calculation is wrong, though. In other words, where does the "infinite energy" go?

Comment: Consider how the field must have been done. Imagine a large but finite coil. When you turn it off, because of inductivity, the coil resists this change and induces a voltage against the change of current, so the energy can be used to run a circuit. Change of magnetic field also induces electric field, so EM waves radiate some of the energy into infinity.

A truly infinite space full of magnetic field is an absurd case that physically doesn't make much sense, but for the purposes of the ring, the field is effectively infinite (because the ring doesn't care how big it is).

Comment: This is a good answer, assuming the ring is rigid and the charge sticks to it (nonconductive material). Also, it might be of interest that the calculation neglects electric forces due to self-induction. This is valid for rings that are made of thick enough rod or wire so the ring's magnetic field does not become too high near and in the ring. For rings made of very thin wire, this would not be the case so the analysis would have to be redone including self-induction.